# Using 'REPLACE' within 'COND' statement

Tags: abap

I am trying to replace a substring in a string based on certain condtions using `COND #`. But not sure where to incorporate `REPLACE` in the syntax.

Normal code:

```
DATA(v_string) = 'My string &1 &2'.

IF v_string CA '&1'.
  REPLACE '&1' WITH 'sub1' in v_string.
ELSEIF v_string CA '&2'.
  REPLACE '&2' WITH 'sub2' in v_string.
ENDIF.
```

I am trying to achieve the same using ABAP 7.5 syntax.

```
v_string = COND #( WHEN v_string CA '&1' THEN REPLACE '&1' WITH 'sub1' in v_string
                   WHEN v_string CA '&2' THEN REPLACE '&2' WITH 'sub2' in v_string ).
```

What is the correct syntax to get the desired results?

Comment: Not related to your question but in your code `CA` is wrongly used, its right operator is interpreted character by character to say "if contains first character or second character or third ...", i.e. if `v_string` contains either `&` or `1`, that's not what you want to do.

Comment: Can't you simply replace twice (which won't do anything if one of the operands is not present)?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I just wanted to show an example and really didn’t think twice about it. Please do edit the question with appropriate code if you have anything in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenconditional_expression_result.htm), the `THEN operand` must be a `a general expression position`, which is defined as

> Reading position in which (alongside a suitable data object) a constructor expression, a table expression, a calculation expression, a built-in function, a functional method, or a method chaining can also be specified.

That means `REPLACE` is not available, but you can use built-in string function [replace](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abenreplace_functions.htm).

```
v_string = COND #( 
  WHEN contains( val = v_string sub = '&1' ) 
    THEN replace( val = v_string sub = '&1' with = 'sub1' occ = 1 )
  WHEN contains( val = v_string sub = '&2' ) 
    THEN replace( val = v_string sub = '&2' with = 'sub2' occ = 1 )
).
```

Comment: This! I had totally forgotten about it. Let me try it out and will mark your answer. Thanks @peterulb